# Ruby example of Net::HTTP for GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'm trying to learn Ruby for the first time. I have some experience in PHP and in PHP, I made a function like

```
function call_api(endpoint,method,arr_parameters='')
{
 // do a CURL call
}
```

Which I would use like

```
call_api('https://api.com/user','get','param=1&param=2');
call_api('https://api.com/user/1','get');
call_api('https://api.com/user/1','post','param=1&param=2');
call_api('https://api.com/user/1','put','param=1&param=2');
call_api('https://api.com/user/1','delete');
```

So far, I've only learned how to do a GET and POST call with Ruby like so:

```
  conn = Net::HTTP.new(API_URL, API_PORT)
  resppost = conn.post("/user", 'param=1', {})
  respget = conn.get("/user?param=1",{})
```

But I don't know how to do a delete and put.  Can someone show sample code for the delete and put calls with the Net::HTTP object?

Comment: There are a number of very good HTTP gems for Ruby, in particular there's Curb which is a well-tested wrapper for libCurl. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients has a good list and, instead of trying to roll your own, it's better to take advantage of the work the others have done.

Comment: Net::HTTP is quite poorly designed and breaks a lot of Ruby conventions in my opinion. I second @theTinMan and recommend using a different http client library if you can

Comment: hey John did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just namespace it:

```
Net::HTTP::Put.new(uri)
```

Same with delete:

```
Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri)
```

You can even do that with your existing calls:

```
conn = Net::HTTP.new(uri)
con.get(path)
```

that is equivalent to:

```
Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
```

Answer (score 3):

For DELETE you can use `conn.delete("/user/1", {})` or

```
request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new("/user/1")
response = conn.request(request)
```

For PUT,

```
response = http.set_request('PUT', "/user/1", "param=1")
```

or 
`Net::HTTP::Put.new(path)`

Answer (score 3):

I like the Faraday gem. I find its design the simplest.

Once you `gem install faraday` you can `require 'faraday'` and do:

```
result = Faraday.get('http://google.es')
```

You can also POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.

```
Faraday.delete('http://google.es')
Faraday.post('http://google.es', {some_parameter: 'hello'})
```

Project: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest a look at [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)? They offer some really awesome examples right on their page to do exactly what you want to do.

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow')

puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

And many more examples of calling different endpoints.